# Should we introduce 'disable-app' as synonym to 'freeze-app'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The official way to "disable" an app (usually [bloatware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloatware) or other [system-apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-apps)) was only introduced with Android 4.0. Before that, apps could be "frozen" with e.g. *Titanium Backup* on rooted devices. Users which started with Android 4.0 or higher thus might never have been confronted with the "freeze" term, and consequentially missing the [freeze-app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freeze-app) – as you can see e.g. with [How can I permanently disable (not uninstall) a stock app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/75868/16575).

Hence my question: Should we introduce [disable-app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disable-app) as synonym to [freeze-app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freeze-app), to give people starting to type "disable" a chance to find the correct tag?

Comment: I think this is a good idea. Should we go one further, and make [tag:disable-app] the canonical one (since this is now the standard) and convert [tag:freeze-app] into a synonym?

Comment: Fine with me as well – and I agree, that would be logical. I just don't know if that "workflow" is implemented for our mods, or if it would only be possible "with complications" not worth the trouble ;)

Comment: As 10 days passed, and this got only positive feedback as far as I can see: What's stopping us from at least creating the synonym?

Comment: I second this motion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synonym created and went ahead and merged [freeze-app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freeze-app) into [disable-app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disable-app)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bryan!